# "Someone logged on to your SQL server from an unusual location."

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm using SQL Server on Azure and just received this security threat message.

> Unauthorized access that exploits an opening in the firewall; legitimate access from a new location.

Google searches don't seem to give me any usable results.

Does this imply that someone actually logged on to my server or just access the API from a new location?
What does this message mean and how should I react to it?

Update: screenshots

**Firewall settings**

[image: Firewall settings]
**Threat message**

[image: Threat]

Comment: Was it you or someone else with credentials? If not, then it was an unauthorized user and you have had a data breach. Why on earth do you have SQL Server open to the Internet?

Comment: I have no ip’s listed in firewall rules. Not even my own.

Comment: What do you have, then? It's a bit difficult to answer, since you're being overly vague about everything. You left out most of the details of the message you received, and you didn't show what you do have in your firewall rules...

Comment: @MichaelHampton I updated my question with screenshots to give better info.

Comment: Possibly the "Allow access to Azure services" could be the problem? Other Azure services are being allowed to access this server?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-threat-detection-overview

> This alert is triggered when there is a change in the access pattern to SQL server, where someone has logged on to the SQL server from an unusual geographical location. In some cases, the alert detects a legitimate action (a new application or developer maintenance). In other cases, the alert detects a malicious action (former employee, external attacker).

I would check if any users/developers that normally works with the SQL have been in Washinton or used any VPN taht terminates in washington. If you can't find a legitme reason for the alert I you should treat it as a breach and re-evaluate your security.

Comment: Just to add to this a little, Azure SQL Query editor is an in browser SQL code runner so whoever triggered this alert has access to the Azure subscription that the database is located in and it's unusual more than likely because it's their first time accessing the resource. Also the editor pokes a hole in the firewall I think to let the connection through so I don't think firewall setup applies here.